# Selenium python web driver doesnt close

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I call `driver.quit()` on test teardown, but the chromedriver process stays alive and doesn't shut down. 
So between executions sometimes Chrome doesn't open at all, and I need to manually shut down the processes.
Someone familiar with this issue?

I'm using selenium 3.5

Comment: All the time or on sometimes? Also are you sure the quit is being called properly

Comment: Sometimes, and im sure

Comment: If I'm debugging and am regularly closing browser sessions or stopping execution, I will end up with a lot of chromedriver.exe processes alive and it's never caused me any problems. Post the teardown code. Put a log message in teardown and make sure that it's getting executed each time you think it is. What actual problem is this causing other than extra processes?

Answer (score 7):

Change your code to below, to be double sure the process is not there after quit

```py
import signal
import os
pid = driver.service.process.pid

driver.quit()
try:
    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)
    print("Killed chrome using process")
except ProcessLookupError as ex:
    pass
```

Comment: `import signal` is missing here

Comment: additionally I would use `signal.SIGKILL` here since this is a fallback for when the driver does not quit

Comment: @Steinfeld, SIGKILL can be a bit brute, that is why you should use SIGTERM first

Comment: Does this still work for you? I am on Chrome 89 and it does not close the window (nor does it throw an exception)

Comment: @EvanHessler, A normal `driver.quit()` should work and this code is just for a handling unexpected scenarios

Comment: @TarunLalwani Not when you hijack an open session through a remote webdriver.